# SQL Server Case statement is not filtering records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I gather that a case statement does not filter records. A developer was INSISTING that it does....

I want to limit the number of records with date range,  but this code does NOT do that.

```
declare @ClientId [int],
        @EventStartDate DateTime,
        @EventEndDate DateTime

set @ClientId = 1
set @EventStartDate = '2016-05-23'
set @EventEndDate = '2016-09-08'

SELECT 
    [CalendarEventId], [ClientId],
    [EventDate],
    [Title],
    [EventText],
    [CreatedBy], [CreatedDate],
    [ModifiedBy], [ModifiedDate],
    CASE 
       WHEN [EventDate] >= @EventStartDate
            AND EventDate <= @EventEndDate 
         THEN 'ACTIVE'
         ELSE 'NOT ACTIVE' 
    END AS [STATUS]
FROM 
    [dbo].[CalendarEvent]
WHERE 
    ClientId = @ClientId
ORDER BY 
    EventDate
```

Comment: include the condition in the `where` clause if you have to filter records.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (not a "statement") - it evaluates to a single, atomic value - and as such, it does **not** do any data filtering of any kind ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assertion that the code does not filter on date is correct and your friend has it wrong.

If you want to filter by the date range too you need to alter your `where` clause to this:

```
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId 
  AND EventDate >= @EventStartDate
  AND EventDate <= @EventEndDate
```

The only thing the `case` expression in your query does is to conditionally set the output of a column in the result set.

Comment: Thank you ,  I am rusty with the sql and they almost had me convinced ...  SMH ,   thx you

Comment: Sorry,  I could not select as answer and had to head home etc..    thx

Answer (score 0):

We can use BETWEEN also, it's also simple to use just providing alternative, though you can use any both returns same result:

```
FROM [dbo].[CalendarEvent]
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId
    AND EventDate BETWEEN @EventStartDate AND @EventEndDate
ORDER BY EventDate
```